# String/char concatenation

Tags: queue, pascal

I must concatenate a STRING variable with a  CHAR counter, but Pascal returns "Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got SHORTSTRING, expected CHAR". I'm working with queues, here is the code:

```
program routes;
uses    crt, queues;
type    graph = array['A'..'E','A'..'E'] of integer;
const   G : graph = ((0,1,0,0,0),
                     (0,0,1,1,1),
                     (0,0,0,1,1),
                     (1,0,1,0,0),
                     (0,0,1,0,0));

procedure bfs(x,y : char; var G : graph);
var f : queue;
    r : string;
    i : char;
begin
    startq(q);
    enqueue(x,q);
    while not emptyq(q) do
        begin
            r := unqueue(q);
            x := r[length(r)];
            if x = y then
                writeln(r)
                    else for i := 'A' to 'E' do
                        if(G[x,i] = 1) and (pos(i,r) = 0) then
                            enqueue(r + i,q);
        end;
    end;

    begin
        bfs('A','E',G);
        readln;
    end;
end.
```

Error occurs at line 25: **enqueue(r + i,q);**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The procedure from "enqueue" is:

```
procedure add(var n : integer); 
begin 
    if n < max then 
        inc(n);
    else n := 1; 
 end; 
 procedure enqueue(x : titem; var f : queue); 
 begin 
     if fullq(q) then err('Queue overload!'); 
         q.item[q.last] := x; 
         add(q.last);
         inc(q.total); 
  end;
```

**EDIT**

Adding the unit's interface:

```
unit queues;

interface

    const max = 50;
    type titem = char;
    type queue = record
                     first, last, total : integer;
                     titem : array[1..max] of titem;
                 end;
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? `queues` is not a standard Pascal unit, so it's difficult to diagnose the problem if we don't know what parameters `enqueue` expects. Also, it's not necessary to repeat your tag information in the title, and it's definitely unacceptable to do so with parens surrounding it * (TagName)*. The tag system works extremely well here to classify questions; please don't try to help it. Thanks.

Comment: Where is `q` defined?

Comment: Don't add details to your question in comments; it's easy to miss, and code can't be properly formatted. Instead, [edit] your question to include it there. You can find the [edit] link directly below the tags in the question itself. You can always edit your own questions. Also, to address a comment to a specific individual in response to a comment they've made, prefix the user name with `@`, as in @Jintei; it puts a notification in their inbox so they see it. You can only do this with one name per comment, so if you need to respond to more than one user you need to use multiple comments.

Comment: @Ken White thanks for directing me and sorry for all the trouble. I've been visiting Stack Overflow for more than three years, but this was my first question.

Comment: @lurker "q" is defined under my unit "Queues".

Comment: So now we know `enqueue` expects a `titem` as its first argument, but what is a `titem`?

Comment: @lurker added the unit's interface above. "titem" is a queue's item.

Answer (score 0):

As said without the definition of enqueue this is hard to judge, but your program calls

```
 enqueue(x,q);
```

once with x is of type CHAR

and later

```
 enqueue(r + i,q);
```

where r+i is a concatenation, thus a string type. This would mean the enqueue procedure needs to be overloaded

You don't mention the used compiler, but if it is turbo pascal, this is the problem, since turbo pascal doesn't support overloading.

Comment: The error message suggest that the problem is that the first argument must be of char type (not string).

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. The "x" and "r+i" that I mentioned are the first argument

Comment: @Marco van de Voort I'm using Dev-Pascal, from Bloodshed Software.

Comment: [Dev-Pascal](http://www.bloodshed.net/devpascal.html) in an IDE, not a compiler.  Which compiler are you using, Free Pascal or GNU Pascal?

Comment: @DavidA Oh sorry... I'm using Free Pascal 1.0.6

Comment: Then the original remark stands. There is no overloading in play (though FPC 1.0.6 has that ability), and you pass an expression that is essentially a shortstring to a procedure expecting a char as first argument. (oh, and bury that old version, and sit on its grave to make absolutely sure it never crawls out)

Comment: @Marco van de Voort, Yes, I understood what you meant. The questioner appears to be new to Pascal so I was just building on your answer, by pointing to the error message which suggest which call to enqueue is correct (i.e. the one where argument 1 has char type). I'm sorry if you thought I was trying to hijack your answer.